# Displaying server's response on activity as textview

Tags: android, textview, httpresponse

I am making a social app in which I am getting response from server side.. i.e emails of profilr friends. I want to take that response to next activity and display as the textview.
How to do this?? Can anyone help me over this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `firstActivity.java` take the response in String and then pass the value to `secondActivity.java` with the help of `Intent.putExtra` and fetch, assign to the related `TextView`

To Put

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", responseString);
startActivity(i);
```

To fetch

```
String stringOnTextView =getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```